# Could not access memory under C++ vector

Tags: c++, gdb, g++, stdvector

I'm using a vector in my program like this:

```
vector<vector<string> > values;
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

when i run the code, it shows "segment fault"

then i try to **gdb** it and i got this:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000008
0x00000001000035be in std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string> >::push_back (this=0x0, __x=@0x7fff5fbff330) at stl_vector.h:602
602     if (this->_M_impl._M_finish != this->_M_impl._M_end_of_storage)
```

What is going on here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no elements in `values`, which means this results in out of bounds access:

```
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

You need to `push_back()` an empty `vector<string>` into `values`:

```
values.push_back(vector<string>());
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

or create `values` with at least one entry (see [vector constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector)):

```
vector<vector<string> > values(1);
```

Comment: Thx,but i think vector will initialize itself when i create it.

Comment: @MrROY, it will initialise itself but it won't insert default elements.

Answer (score 5):

This defines an empty vector of vectors:

```
vector<vector<string> > values;
```

This pushes a string into the first vector:

```
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

Only there is no first vector yet! Try

```
vector<string> v;
values.push_back(v);
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
values[0].push_back("test words");
```

Here, you are trying to access index 0 which does not exist. Hence you are getting

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
```

You could do it this way for simplicity.

```
vector<string> v;
vector<vector<string> > values;
v.push_back("test words");
values.push_back(v);
```

Answer (score 0):

`values[0].push_back("test words");`

I think you meant to insert a string into the first element which is a vector in the `values` vector, which is a vector of vector. But the internal vector is not yet initialized.

Try this:

```
vector<vector<string> > values;
vector<string> string_vector;
string_vector.push_back("test words");
values.push_back(string_vector);
```